# Two times same onclick function - only one works

Tags: javascript

I am desperate on this.

I create a list with an image and some description and other data.

The image and the description should be linked the same way.

The description link(onclick event) work fine:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_object('<?php echo $itemId."','".$identifier; ?>');  return false;"><?php echo (string)$flat.'</a><br />'; ?>
```

But around the image it doesn't:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_object('<?php echo $itemId.','.$identifier; ?>');return false;">
 <img src="<?php echo (string)$image_url; ?>" class="list_image"></img>
</a>
```

Why? I do not understand, I tried several other ways, with including the onclick into the image, making a span out of the a.. Nothing works.

If I click on the image, I see in the javascript console that the request get started, but it does not load the page.

I do not understand since the two requests are exact same and immitedly behind another (inside a table)

please help!

Comment: This will be more readable `echo "$itemId','$identifier";`

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: The generated HTML would help a lot. Also, even if this should not be problem, the img tag should not be closed like this. Depending on whether you are doing HTML or XHTML, it should be just open (no </img>) or short-closed (<img ... />).

Comment: thank you all! I was stupid missing quotes my fault... I feel so dump now.. need coffee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing some quotes:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_object('<?php echo $itemId."','".$identifier; ?>');return false;">
 <img src="<?php echo (string)$image_url; ?>" class="list_image"></img>
</a>
```

In your version, you call `show_object('someitemid,someidentifier')` but you want to call `show_object('someitemid','someidentifier')` as you do in your first  `<a>`-tag.

Comment: DAMN IT! thank you so much this is the third time I run on these stupid quotes I CANNOT believe this!!!! Thank you all so much sorry for bothering with such stupid questions.. I think its time for coffee break

Answer (score 1):

How is that "exactly the same" ?

```
"show_object('<?php echo $itemId."','".$identifier; ?>');  return false;"
"show_object('<?php echo $itemId.','.$identifier; ?>');return false;"
```

I suggest you double check the quotes, or copypaste the working one into the other, then come back to us if it's not fixed :)